# With JPA, EclipseLink, JSF and reporting dynamically

Tags: jsf, jpa, eclipselink

I have 3 database tables and each table is represented by an Entity Class. What I want to do is to Join these three tables with a special condition and select maximum one column from each table wrap them in an object and display this object on the JSF tier using a data table.

Is it possible to do this using dynamic entity class without playing with my entity classes? Has anyone got a solution for this problem?

Will appreciate any help
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you clarify 'select maximum one column from each table'. Is it going to be always the same 3 columns or the column from each table can change depending on the query?

Comment: Yes column from each table may change depending on the query. Thanks

Comment: Where is the logic to determine which columns to select: in the SQL, in some computation based on the result?

Comment: Using native query, the selected columns won't be the same, they might be different. So I don't want to create entity class for each native query or play with entity classes alter with their schema.

Comment: You can build the query dynamically putting the required columns in the select list, assign the returned objects to a bean with fields defined as `Object` and pass them to the JSF tier that will call the `get` methods on the bean to access column values.

Comment: You really want/need to reinvent the wheel when you can use a report tool like iReport?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: I am already using iReport and Jasper Report for report generating. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @remigio I found a solution quite similar to your recommendation. I will use DynamicEntities (EclipseLink) and generate a dynamic type and use it on the JSF tier. I will post the example code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a constructor query, or just simply select multiple values and get an Object[] back.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Constructors

You could also just select the objects, then extract what you need from them in Java.